# How to check If value is numeric In SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a report in SSRS. My dataset query returns me multiple output and I show them in the report in every new line new record.

Here is the query. Now I want to check if the value return is numeric or not. Here is my expression.

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!QuestionId.Value, Fields!QuestionID.Value, 
Fields!ScalarValue.Value, "myResponse"), Constants.VbCrLf)
```

I Tried working on IIF(isnumeric ... ) but as it returns me multiple result, It does not allow me to format. I want to format that two 2 decimal if the output is numeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IsNumeric` is useful here, but the problem with `IIf` is that is doesn't short circuit, so you might run into errors if you're casting data.

For example, if you use `CDec` to allow numeric formatting to be applied to a string, it will be applied in all cases and throw an error when the string is not numeric.

A safe way to do this is to create a simple Custom Code function to handle the formatting and use this in the `LookupSet` expression.

So add some Custom Code to the report like:

```
Public Function FormattedString(ByVal st as String) as String

    If IsNumeric(st)

      Return Format(CDec(st), "N2")

    End If

  Return st

End Function
```

And change your expression to use this new `FormattedString` function:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!QuestionId.Value, Fields!QuestionID.Value, 
Code.FormattedString(Fields!ScalarValue.Value), "myResponse"), Constants.VbCrLf)
```

I tested against the following data:

[image]

A simple table with the above expression looks as required:

[image]

So it's working for me against a mix of data - you can change the formatting logic in the Custom Code as required.